# array key values being emptied/zero'd immediately after being assigned

Tags: php

I have a form that sets up the page's input field values using PHP like:

```
// create and fill inputVarsArr with keys that have empty vals
$troubleInsertInputVarsArr = array_fill_keys(array('status', 'discoverDate', 'resolveDate', 'ticketIssued', 'eqptSystem', 'alarmCode', 'troubleDescription', 'troubleshootingSteps', 'resolveActivities', 'notes'), '');

if (isset ($_POST['insert'])) { // update DB site details 
    foreach ($troubleInsertInputVarsArr as $key => $val) {
        if ($key !== 'discoverDate' && $key !== 'resolveDate') { //deal with dates separately below
            $val = $_SESSION[$key] = sanitizeText($_POST[$key]);
            echo '<br>(' . __LINE__ . ') ' . $key . ': ' . $val . ' ';
        } // close IF ; line 47 echo
    } // close FOREACH

    foreach ($troubleInsertInputVarsArr as $key => $val) {
        echo '<br>(' . __LINE__ . ') ' . $key . ': ' . $val . ' ';
    } // close FOREACH // line 52 echo
}
```

The input vars echo'd in the `if` conditional nested in the `foreach` loop (echo' on line 47) print out as I expect (values entered into the form page's input fields):

```
(47) status: Outstanding
(47) ticketIssued: no
(47) eqptSystem: Tower Lights
(47) alarmCode: Visual
(47) troubleDescription: - no description yet -
(47) troubleshootingSteps: - no steps yet taken -
(47) resolveActivities: - no activities yet decided -
(47) notes: - no notes -
```

But then the same **key-val** pairs in the same array echo'd in the `foreach` loop that immediately follows (echo'd on line 52), without any further variable processing having occurred, prints out empty values for each key:

```
(52) status:
(52) discoverDate:
(52) resolveDate:
(52) ticketIssued:
(52) eqptSystem:
(52) alarmCode:
(52) troubleDescription:
(52) troubleshootingSteps:
(52) resolveActivities:
(52) notes:
```

Somehow the array's key values are being zero'd out right after they are assigned and I can't figured out how or why. Can anyone see an obvious reason why this might be occurring?

Comment: Man, your a creating the `$troubleInsertInputVarsArr` with empty values `''`, what did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign values to $troubleInsertInputVarsArr, only keys.
You could try this:

```
   foreach ( $troubleInsertInputVarsArr as $key => $val ) {
      $troubleInsertInputVarsArr[$key] = sanitizeText( $_POST[ $key ]); 
      if ( $key !== 'discoverDate' && $key !== 'resolveDate' ) { 
          $val = $_SESSION[ $key ] = sanitizeText( $_POST[ $key ] );
          echo '<br>(' . __LINE__ . ') ' . $key . ': ' . $val . ' ';
      } 
    }
```

Comment: I find that preferable to assigning stuff by reference.

Comment: Read my comment on the other answer :-)

Comment: @delboy1978uk why on earth would you prefer that over using a reference?

Comment: I don't like the multiple assignments, I'll give you that

Comment: You've actually changed the behaviour of the original code beyond the bug fix. I don't think he wants the date values in the array (as per his first "expected" output example)

Comment: Then he should take those keys out of the troubleInsertInputVarsArr  array, and add them back in wherever he wants to start dealing with them. That, or unset the two after the foreach, which is less sensible.

Comment: Whatever, he isn't asking for advice on the dates. The main problem is that you've provided copy-pastable code which is incorrect based on the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `$val = $_SESSION[ $key ] = sanitizeText( $_POST[ $key ] );` line does not change the `$troubleInsertInputVarsArr` array as `$val` is a copy of the array element value, not a reference.

Change the foreach so that $val is a reference.

`foreach ( $troubleInsertInputVarsArr as $key => &$val ) {`

Comment: Thats right until it comes to the 2 skipped fields in the first foreach `discoverDate, resolveDate`. wired stuff in OP code ;-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions that's a separate issue

Comment: When i see OP code, just fixing it, will help, but will teach nothing :-) Whatever, it was just a note.